# How to find a parent's child with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a menu that looks like this:

```
<ul class="menu">
  <li><a href="#">zing</a></li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">page</a>
    <ul>
      <li>foo</li>
      <li>bar</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I'd like the sub menu to fadeIn when I hover over the **page** link.
This is my code so far but for some reason it's not working and I don't think this is the correct way to achieve this anyways:

```
$('.menu li a:nth-child(2)').hover(function(){
    $('.menu li ul').fadeIn(150);
}, function(){
    $('.menu li ul').fadeOut(150);
});
```

Anyone know how I can reach my goal according to best standards to make the submenu of the 2nd li to appear when I hover over **page**?

Comment: There is not a `sub_menu` class.

Comment: Fixed the post; i forgot that i removed the class lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would probably be a good idea to have your hovers only apply to menus that have a submenu. You could do something like this:

```
$('.menu > li > a').filter(function(){
    if( $(this).siblings('ul').length ){ return true; }
}).hover(
    function(){ $(this).siblings('ul').fadeIn(150); }
    ,function(){ $(this).siblings('ul').fadeOut(150); }
);
```

Comment: This works! Would you mind explaining the code? I have no idea what you did here :O

Comment: ohh i think i got it; it checks if the `a` tag has any siblings. it this returns true, it activates the hover function which fades in the `ul` which is a sibling of the current hovered element. Did i get it right? What is `filter()`'s function though?

Comment: Sure :) The .filter function is a way to filter a set of results with a selector or a custom function (return true for each element that should be included in the results). It will loop through the first selector and $(this) will be each of the elements in that selector. For each of those elements it looks to see if there are any "siblings" that are UL elements and if so the filter function returns true meaning it should be included in the selection. Afterwards it simply sets the hover to fadeIn and fadeOut any sibling ULs of that anchor.

Comment: You got it, curse my re-wording of things! The filter() function can actually accept another selector, a custom function, an element or even another jQuery object to filter against. You can find it in the jQuery documentation: http://api.jquery.com/filter/

Answer (score 1):

The `nth-child` selector needs to be applied to the `<li>` element not the `<a>`.

```
$('.menu li ul li:nth-child(2)').hover(function(){
    $('.menu li ul').fadeIn(150);
}, function(){
    $('.menu li ul').fadeOut(150);
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9u3V7/

Comment: I wouldnt use `nth-child` at all... what if other elements start getting submenus? Better to just detect if an `a` has an adjacent `ul` sibling and then show that.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that the submenu appears even when the `li` is hovered, which is not the idea. It should only appear when `a` is hovered because the `li` tags of my menu are *huge*.

Comment: @imjp so do you want it to appear which `a` or `li` is hovered over?

Answer (score 0):

Check this fiddle out: http://jsfiddle.net/vPLAc/3/

No need for counting children that way. Every list item with a submenu will react to this code.

Comment: `li a` needs to activate the `.hover()` function, not `li` alone :)